# Redirect issue after jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have the following code that should redirect to the index page of my website after the AJAX method completes. It redirect however the page doesn't have any content loaded, it is just an empty page with a background.

```
function login(){
    var uname = document.getElementById("UserName").value;
    var upass = document.getElementById("Password").value;

    var response = $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "../../php_scripts/ajax.php",
        data: "call=login(" + uname + ", " + upass + ")",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    window.location.replace("http://www.domainname.com");
}
```

What could cause this problem? could this be a server issue?

[EDIT]

Also if I put the redirect call above the AJAX everything loads correctly.

[EDIT 2]

If I use an asynchronous AJAX with callback method of any kind it causes exact same problem. I'm beginning to think that this is a jQuery bug.

Comment: Redefining `AJAX` without **A**

Comment: @user3585147 check like this `if (response.readyState==4 && response.status==200)`

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark your post as solved. The best way to do this is to add your own answer and self-accept, so it is clear which answer helped you the most. I've done this for you (marked as community wiki, so no-one gets rep points) but in future you can do it yourself if you like. Would you tick that one now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

After hours of tinkering I found the culprit of the problem. It had nothing to do with JavaScript or AJAX - in fact the error originated in the SQL database. There was an incorrectly setup up relationship constraint which caused my PHP record update method to fail.

This made the method return a null back to the calling method which then was saved into a variable and then later a member method was called on that variable. Calling a member method on a null type broke the PHP which is why nothing was displayed on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the redirect on success of the ajax call.

If your request is async: false then you should not use ajax.done(), ajax.fail() etc methods to register the callback methods, instead you need to pass the callback methods using success/error/complete options to the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  success: function(){
        window.location.replace("http://www.domainname.com");
  },
  error: function(){
  },
  complete: function(){
        window.location.replace("http://www.domainname.com");
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried that, this is a synchronous not an asynchronous ajax call (note async false).

Comment: See updated post. If your request is async false then you should not use ajax.done() you should use instead the callback methods using success/error... etc.

Comment: @Johnston ↑↑↑ That's correct, async false being deprecated for deferred/promise object

Comment: I'm loading the latest version "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" but I tried to use some older versions as well (e.g. jquery-1.9.1.min.js), same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use `complete` callback to redirects to desired page. After completing request then you'll be redirected to the page.

Try this:

```
function login(){
    // use jquery anyway if you reference to this
    var uname = $("#UserName").val();
    var upass = $("#Password").val();

    var response = $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "../../php_scripts/ajax.php",
        data: "call=login(" + uname + ", " + upass + ")",
        async: false,
        complete: function() { 
            // redirects is done with below code
            window.location.replace("http://www.domainname.com");
        }
    }).responseText;
}
```

Comment: Great you explain behavior of change

Comment: Note : User is making a sync call not asyc

Comment: how is it going to hurt `window.location.href = "http://www.domainname.com";`??..No not at all..Your code is exact copy of what OP posted..with some invalid tweaks

Comment: My bad, I put the replace because it is better than href